# Get a mean average group by on hh:mm:ss time data in python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, timedelta

I have a pandas dataframe with the following example data:

```
Group   Time
1       01:40:00
1       01:32:00
2       00:56:31
```

I want my output to be:

```
Group   Time
1       01:36:00
2       00:56:31
```

When running a dtype, both Group and Time are stored as objects.

I have done some reading and supposedly you can only do this by converting the data into hh:mm:ss:ms. I have tried using the timedelta function but have had no luck.

```
def rreplace(s, old, new, occurrence):
    li = s.rsplit(old, occurrence)
    return new.join(li)
df['New Time']=pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'].apply(lambda x: rreplace('00:{}'.format(x), ':', '.', 1)))

df.groupby(['Group'])['New Time'].mean()
```

Now I know this code pushes it down a layer. i.e. seconds are now milliseconds. but i would like this to do the reverse and show me the correct hh:mm:ss time in hh:mm:ss:ms format so I can perform mathematical operations on it.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me working aggregate by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with `sum` and counts by `size` and then divide columns, tested in pandas 0.25.1:

```
df['New Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])
df = df.groupby(['Group'])['New Time'].agg(['sum','size'])
df = df['sum'].div(df['size']).reset_index(name='Time')
print (df)
   Group     Time
0      1 01:36:00
1      2 00:56:31
```